# How can I efficiently load test a webapp with a headless browser?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, load-testing, derbyjs

I have experience with a few headless browsers, but only for testing and not load testing. What's the best way to launch 500-1000 websocket clients to load test the application? Is it as simple as just looping a bunch with a `setTimeout` that gets longer incrementally?

I can build out the actual tests myself, I'm just curious which framework is best suited for this.

I have experience with ZombieJS and PhantomJS (along with Casper and Webspecter).

Comment: Are you testing the client or the server? If you're just testing the server, why not just create a ton of websocket clients in node or something?

Comment: I'm testing the frontend client.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to do scalability/load testing on your server. How do you test client side performance with hundreds of thousands of virtual clients? anyway I assume you already tried using headless phantom clients. That's the same thing I also tried and it worked for me well I monitored CPU, network throughput and Memory usage using some utility plugins.

There is a  plugin which does JMeter integration for websocket protocol. This might be helpful

https://github.com/kawasima/jmeter-websocket/